# Suggestion for S3 key name

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an C# application where user can upload images to S3 bucket. Its an e-commerce application so I expect high load. I am planning to prefix images name and upload to S3 to avoid any duplicate or special character case
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-key-guidelines).

In this case how would I access same uploaded image back in my application when user wants to access if name has changed(I am not storing original and changed name mapping in database) ?

What are best pratices should I follow to store & retrieval of  images in S3 and key name creation ?

Comment: The best practice would be to store the name in a database so you can look it up later. But you said you aren't doing that.

Comment: Yeah I cant modify database schema

Comment: Why not use datetimestamp and call it a day?

Comment: As @Nate suggests below, you could perhaps use S3 as the database by storing the original image name and user name as metadata on the S3 object. You'd give each S3 object a unique, calculated key (for example a UUID), store the original information as metadata, then return the actual S3 key to the client.

Answer (score 1):

If you want each user has the isolated space name:

```
FullKey= MD5(UserName+DateAndTimeofRegistration) + KeyName
```

Comment: What is key name here , how would I retrieve it back via original image name ?

Comment: It can be the original name or any combination you want, for special characters filter them; you need a function for that.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is that you **must use a database**.

This is the only way you will know:

- What objects exist
- Who created them
- Who should be allowed to access them

Once you have a large number of objects in a bucket (eg thousands), calls to Amazon S3 to obtain a list of objects are **not efficient**. They could take considerable time to retrieve the list.

So, unless you put all responsibility on the user to remember the name of files that they uploaded, you will need to manage the list yourself.

Steps would be:

- When they **upload** a file, store it in Amazon S3 with a [Universally unique identifier - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)
- **Add an entry to a database** recording: original file name, unique name, user, upload data and any appropriate metadata for the object (eg access permissions, expiry date, and whatever your app wants)
- When a user wants to **view a list of files**, retrieve it from the database
- When a user wants to **download an object**, lookup the unique ID from the database, then create a Pre-Signed URL to allow them to access it from Amazon S3

Also think about how users can delete an object, what should happen if they upload an object again with the same name (overwrite, or keep both?), whether files should expire after some period of time (or you will pay for storage forever)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a metadata key for original file name and user to each image.  Then on retrieval search by the original file name key.

Comment: Can you provide an example ?